# fancybox 3 - how to enlarge image and keep enlarging with next image

Tags: fancybox, fancybox-3

The images have texts (imagine comics).
In fancybox gallery, I click an image thumbnail and see its big image.

I enlarge it to read texts in the image (in mobile screen, texts are too small to read),
and I click 'next arrow' to see next image.
But then enlarging turns off, and I should enlarge image again.

This is annoying since I have to enlarge every single image.

I want enlarging to be kept until I shrink image back to its original size.
How can I achieve this with fancybox3?

Answer (score 1):

### scaleToActual method

> Scale image to the actual size of the image.

Docs:
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#instance_methods

```
// Scale image to the actual size of the image
instance.scaleToActual( x, y, duration );
```

Code Example:

```
$('[data-fancybox="images"]').fancybox({
  animationEffect : false,
  afterShow : function(instance, current) {
    instance.scaleToActual(222, 222)
  }
})
```

**Codepen:**
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/omoOKo?editors=1010